# Bootstrap 4 PHP Login won't hide the alert

Tags: php, forms, authentication, bootstrap-4, alerts

I'm having issues with my PHP login. I'm using bootstrap 4 cards the alert class is always showing even though I hide it..

There is a check when I submit my form for several thing: Do the email and password match? Does the email exist in the database etc.

When one of the checks fails the user will not login and an error will be stored in the php: $error = 1;

The problem is that the alert is always showing even though the form is not yet submitted, which is fine when the login fails.

[Here's my Login Form with alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXrLt.png)

Here my Bootstrap 4 code with php:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger <?php if(!isset($error)) echo 'hide';?>">
        Invalid username/password! Email administrator in link below to recover it.
    </div>
      <div class="alert alert-warning <?php if(!isset($inactive)) echo 'hide';?>">
        This account is no longer valid. Thank you!
     </div>
 <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
```

Heres my PHP Login code:

```
 <?php
        include('connection.php');
        if (isset($_POST['proceed'])) {
                $username = $_POST['login'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                /***** GUIDANCE *****/
                $guidance = "SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE Faculty_ID = ? AND Password = ? AND Position='Guidance' ";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($guidance);
                $stmt->bind_param('is', $username, $password);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();



                $student = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE Student_ID = ? AND Password = ? ";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($student);
                $stmt->bind_param('is', $username, $password);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result2 = $stmt->get_result();
                if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {

                    $row = $result -> fetch_object();
                        if($row->Status!='Active'){
                            $inactive = 1;
                            }else{
                            $_SESSION['access'] = 1;
                            $_SESSION['login'] = $row -> Faculty_ID;
                            $_SESSION['Faculty_Firstname'] = $row -> Faculty_Firstname;
                            header('Location: guidance/index.php');
                        }
                                elseif ($result2 -> num_rows > 0) {

                                $row = $result2 -> fetch_object();
                                    $_SESSION['access'] = 3;
                                    $_SESSION['Student_ID'] = $row -> Student_ID;
                                    //$_SESSION[] = $row ->
                                    header('Location:student/index.php ');
                    }else{
                                $error = 1;
                }
                }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think show or hide class is not working with your div where you set class of alert and alert-danger. Even I am just keeping "hide" manually without php code, its not hiding the div element. So, there might be other way to hide the div. This trick might work with Bootstrap3.

Try using `d-none` instead of hide and you might get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Your alert must be hidden at start, and it also must be dismissible, I advice you using javascript, so according to the doc you have

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade hide" role="alert"> <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below. <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button> </div>
```

I assume you are using bootstrap 4.1,  here's the [doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/alerts/).
to a better understanding of the hide/show class try this [pen](https://codepen.io/Knewtone/pen/XBYxXw) and change the "***hide***" class with "***show***" class